# How Can I check Spring Boot version and Spring Data REST version without pom.xml?

Tags: spring, version

I checked Spring Boot Version with the command below.

```
org.springframework.core.SpringVersion.getVersion()
```

How Can I know if I am using Spring Data REST?
And how Can I check this version without pom.xml?

Best Regards,
wbbae